# Best way to use multiple functions in jquery plugin development

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Suppose I have a plugin named jQuery.area.js and it have various methods as triangle, square etc

```
$.fn.area = function( options ){

        if(options == 'sqaure')
        {
            square();
        }else if(options == 'circle')
        {
            circle();
        }
       ......and so on
}
```

How do I use this? What is the proper way to have multiple function in a jQuery plugin?

```
$("#show").click( function(){
        $(".area1").area('circle',{
            x : 5
        });
```

Is this the right way?